# When lots of View Layers = Way too small text in Compositing Tab

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, viewlayers

I currently have a Blender scene where I have TONS of View Layers.
Now, when I go in the Compositing Tab, and try to assign a View Layer to an Output Node, there's so many View Layers that if I want to chose the latest, I have to zoom out too much and I can't read the View Layer names anymore.
Is there another way to do this? A way I could see the text bigger and maybe scroll through them?
Thank you!
[image: View Layers Name too small]

Comment: Would be helpful for you have them named (even in a way where name collects some group of layers ... Or use preffix or suffix) ... Like that you can click and type few letters of name to filter such long list. I'm on tablet so I can't confirm if Batch Rename could save you from manual tedious work.

Comment: Hey vklidu! thanks for answering. Actually, i named them already. But someone over at blenderartist.com gave me the answer: you can Ctrl+Mouse wheel on the dropdown of viewlayers, that way i don't even have to open that huuuge window! 

Comment: Sure you can ... I just didnt see this as solution ... to scroll list like yours any time you need to set something? ... Uf :) Anyway, great if you found it as solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can change them here in your preferences (Menu: edit->Preferences):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Chris! Will look into that!